# Template operation on base function

Tags: c++, templates

I have an interface `IImage`, which is derived by a template class `CTypedImage`, whith the pixel type as template argument.

```
class IImage
{
public:
    virtual ~IImage() {}
    ...

    static int IImage::ReadFile(IImage* &outImage, QString path, QString file);
};

template<class T>
class CTypedImage : public IImage
{
    ...
};
```

This way, I can just call:

```
IImage* image = nullptr;
int ret = IImage::ReadFile(image, path, file);
```

without knowledge of the underlying pixel type.

This piece of code is generic and may be used in many projects, so I don't want to implement specific processings in it.

Instead, I want to localy define the operations to apply on the data. The problem is that in my main code, I don't have acces to the type of pixel (and I don't want to handle it if it's not necessary), so I can't just call

```
OperationOnData<type_of_pixel>(image);
```

I tried with this idea:

- Adding a function `CallOperation` to the interface `IImage`:

  ```
  virtual int CallOperation(class IOperation* op) = 0;
  ```

  with

  ```
  class IOperation
  {
  public:
      virtual ~IOperation() {}
      virtual int Apply(IImage* img) = 0;
  };
  ```
- Define the specific operations locally:

  ```
  template<class T>
  class MyOperation: public IOperation
  {
  public:
      MyOperation() {}
      ~MyOperation() {}

      int Apply(IImage* img);
  };

  template<class T> int MyOperation::Apply(IImage* img)
  {
      /* do things with pixels of type T */
  }
  ```
- Call the operation with the type as a template argument::

  ```
  template<class T>
  int CTypedImage<T>::CallOperation(IOperation* op)
  {
      if (op == nullptr)
          return -1;
      return op->Apply<T>(this);
  }
  ```

But all the variations I tried around this idea did not work, either because it did not compile (for example because I can't have a virtual fonction in a template) or it doesn't use the derived `Apply` function.

I tried different syntaxes, but I can't find a way to achieve what I want.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, even telling me I need to rewrite all the thing.

Comment: trying to understand what you want here. Are you saying that you want to be able to perform specific operations on the data in the image, without knowing the form of the data?

Comment: You can have virtual functions in templates. The virtual functions themselves cannot be templates, however.

Comment: I suggest you to give a look at visitor pattern, since your IOperation class is very close to it.

Comment: @RichardHodges The `ReadFile` loader already put the data in a known form (N-dimensions array). The data type will probably be a standard numeral type (but it could be something else, like RGB structs for example). The `IOperation`-derived class will work on the array, with a default implementation for standard types and some specializations for special types.

Comment: Then, given an operatiojn, you have a function or so for every pixel type, right?

Comment: No, I have a default template implementation working on type T, which allows me to work with standard numeral data, and, if needed, some specifications for other types. All simple types ([u]int, [u]char, [u]short, double, etc.) are handled by the default implementation. If an operation is targeted at simple types only (ie there is no reason to work on special types), no specialisations should be needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an accept virtual function to your CTypedImage like this:

```
template<class T>
class CTypedImage : public IImage
{

    ...
   virtual void accept(IOperation *operation)
   {
       operation->Apply(this) ;
   }
};
```

Your operation then will be defined like this:

```
class IOperation
{
public:
    virtual ~IOperation() {}
    virtual int Apply(CTypedImage<char> * img) = 0; // one function for every kind of pixel
    virtual int Apply(CTypedImage<short> * img) = 0; // a typelinst could be handy 
                            // while defining the type set but that's another story
};
```

A concrete operation may be defined like this

```
class MyIOperation : public Operation
{
public:
    virtual ~IOperation() {}
    virtual int Apply(CTypedImage<char> * img) 
    {                      // forward to generic implementation
        ApplyT(img) ;      // note: image type is known here 
    }
    virtual int Apply(CTypedImage<short> * img) 
    { ApplyT(img) ;}      

    template <class T>
    int ApplyT(CTypedImage<T> * img)
    { 
        // generic implementation
    }
};
```

So given a pointer to an operation and a generic image you can apply the operation like this

```
IOperation *operation ;
IImage *image ;

image->accept(operation) ;
```

This is an application of the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern), where the operation act as visitor.

Comment: Visual Studio is not happy with operation->Apply(this) : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'CTypedImage<T> *' to 'CTypedImage<T> *'

Comment: Ok, I needed to define all the types I can encounter for now... But if I add other types later, I'll have to review all my existing code, no ?

Comment: Yes, if you add another type then you have to add a function to IOperation. A typelist can be handy for that, or some other mechanism that allows you to define the types used in just one place.

Comment: I do not understand the error message. There must be some other detail missing.

Comment: Ther error message was due to the fact that I did not define all the types, it works now. Thanks for your help !